# How get size of an array in json response? rest assured API, JAVA

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I found a lot of topics with this question on this portal, but anyway I was not able to achieve what I need. I keep getting the next exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "roles" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function` .

Partially my code:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;


String baseURItest = RestAssured.baseURI = "http://testapi.test.com/testapps");
Response response;
response = given().when().get("/getAllRoles?token=token");
countRoles=response.body().path("$..roles.size()");
System.out.println(countRoles);
```

console output:

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "roles" was used but
> not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function
```

and json body response:

```
{
    "Message": "",
    "Status": 200,
    "Data": {
        "errors": [],
        "roles": [
            {
                "ROLEKEY": "1",
                "ROLEID": 1,
                "ROLENAME": "name1",
                "ROLEDESCRIPTION": "1"
            },
            {
                "ROLEKEY": "2",
                "ROLEID": 2,
                "ROLENAME": "name2",
                "ROLEDESCRIPTION": "12"
            },
            {
                "ROLEKEY": "3",
                "ROLEID": 3,
                "ROLENAME": "name3",
                "ROLEDESCRIPTION": "x"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I also tried :

> ```
>   JsonPath jsonPathValidator = response.jsonPath();
>   System.out.println(jsonPathValidator.get("$..ROLEKEY").toString());
> ```

I would say I tried a lot of different ways that I found in google, but each time I will get the same error. Can someone please explain to me what am I missing here, please? Or what should I do? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** You misunderstand JsonPath in Rest-Assured.

- `$..ROLEKEY` is [JsonPath jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) syntax.
- JsonPath in Rest-Assured uses groovy [GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) internally.

Note from Rest-Assured [wiki](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-1---json).

> Note that the "json path" syntax uses Groovy's GPath notation and is not to be confused with Jayway's JsonPath syntax.

**Solution:** you can choose one of two ways below:

1. Use JsonPath jayway by adding this to pom.xml (or gradle.build)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
Response res = given().when().get("/getAllRoles?token=token");
JsonPath.read(res.asString(), "$..ROLEKEY");
```

2. You can use JsonPath from Rest-Assured.

```
List<String> roles = response.jsonPath().getList("Data.roles.ROLEKEY");
System.out.println(roles);
//[1,2,3]
```

Comment: you really found the real problem :) I just had to specify a full path to that list, since that way with `getList` method I actually tried first. `"Data.roles.ROLEKEY"` - this works as expected! And now I can get rid of my crazy workaround steps with counting commas... Thank you so much for your help and for providing extra documentation!